# How do you exclude files and folders from the tfpt scorch command?

Tags: tfs

I need to synchronize my `c:\Source\MyProject\Trunk` workspace folder with tfs using the team foundation server power tools command tfpt scorch. I want the scorch command to skip the folder `c:\Source\Myproject\Trunk\\.git`, all its children and the file `c:\Source\Myproject\Trunk\\.gitignore`.

How do I specify the "filespec" for the /excludes command line parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would (obviously) want to test this, but a filespec (or itemspec) in TFS speak is the local or server path to a file/folder.  Therefore you should be able to pass /excludes:c:\Source\Myproject\Trunk.git and I would expect it to be excluded recursively.  Additionally, as I understand itemspecs I would have thought if you did /excludes:*.git that would exclude any files or folders with the .git extension.

That said, I've never used the scorch command so it would be worth making a backup of the Trunk.git folder before you run this command though in-case my guess is incorrect...

Comment: Here is what worked for me /exclude:*.git* this excludes both the .gitignore file and the .git folder and its children.

Comment: @Ahmed - upvote for not `/exclude` not `/excludes`.
Could you possibly extend your example to show a list of directorys or files? I'm apparently having some trouble understanding `/exclude:filespec[,..]` as directed by `tfpt scorch /?`.

Answer (score 7):

Just as a complement to Martin's answer:

`tfpt scorch` will make sure your workspace is identical to the repository. It doesn't really matter what folder you are in now. `tfpt scorch` will always start from the root of the current workspace.

If you want to **include** only a particular folder inside the workspace:

```
tfpt scorch c:\my\foo\directory
```

If you want to **include** just a particular file type:

```
tfpt scorch *.cs
```

If you want to **exclude** a particular folder

```
tfpt scorch /excludes:c:\my\foo\directory
```

If you want to **exclude** a particular file type:

```
tfpt scorch /excludes:*.cs
```

You can combine multiple directories and filetypes separating `filespecs` by space.